# GCC macro expansion to call another macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I am writing an application in C (gcc) which does a lot of string-comparison. Always one unknown/dynamic-string with a long list of compile-time constant strings.
So I figured I hash the dynamic string and compare the resulting hash with precomputed hashes of the constant strings.

The do this I have the hash-algorithm in a function (for the dynamic runtime-strings) and as a macro so that gcc evaluates the hash during compile-time.

I got this:

```
#define HASH_CALC(h, s) ((h) * 33 + *(s))
#define HASH_CALC1(s) (HASH_CALC(hash_calc_start, s))
#define HASH_CALC2(s) (HASH_CALC(HASH_CALC1(s), s + 1))
#define HASH_CALC3(s) (HASH_CALC(HASH_CALC2(s), s + 2))
#define HASH_CALC4(s) (HASH_CALC(HASH_CALC3(s), s + 3))
#define HASH_CALC5(s) (HASH_CALC(HASH_CALC4(s), s + 4))
//--> cut ... goes till HASH_CALC32

static const unsigned long hash_calc_start = 5381;
unsigned long hash_str (const char* c);

void func () {
    //This string is not constant ... just in this case to show something
    char dynStr = "foo";
    unsigned long dynHash = hash_str (dynStr);

    //gcc produces a cmp with a constant number as foo is hashed during compile-time
    if (dynHash == HASH_CALC3("foo")) {
    }
}
```

Now to the question:

Is it possible to create a macro which expands to HASH_CALCX(s) where X is the length of the constant string passed to the macro?

```
//Expands to HASH_CALC3("foo")
if (dynHash == HASH_CALCX("foo")) {
}
//Expands to HASH_CALC6("foobar")
if (dynHash == HASH_CALCX("foobar")) {
}
```

I tried this but it does not work.

```
#define HASH_STRLEN(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])-1)
#define HASH_MERGE(x,y) x ## y
#define HASH_MERGE2(x,y) HASH_MERGE(x,y)
#define HASH_CALCX(s) (HASH_MERGE2(HASH_CALC, HASH_STRLEN(s))(s))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not necessary. `strlen` works perfectly well for string constants, returning a compiletime constant.

Comment: @Damon Well ... #define HASH_CALCX(s) (HASH_MERGE2(HASH_CALC, strlen(s))(s)) does not work either as the strlen("") gets not expanded.

Comment: How is `hash_calc_start` defined? `#define hash_calc_start 0`?

Comment: Actually it's static const unsigned long hash_calc_start = 5381; but it's no problem to define it as macro-constant if that helps my problem :-)

Comment: Have you ttied to just call your hash function instead of using a macro? If the function definition is in the same translation unit, any modern compiler is ought to be able to inline it and eventually reduce to a constant.

Comment: That is the problem ---> gcc does inline the function instead of just putting the resulting constant there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in C, string decomposition is not a constant expression. The following is invalid:

```
switch (x) {
case "a"[0]:
  ...
}
```

Constant expressions in preprocessor are similar. The following is invalid:

```
#if "a"[0] == 'a'
  ...
#endif
```

If you do not need to use your hash codes in `switch` statements why not to precompute those values during an initialization phase of your program, store results into variables and then simply use them in tests?

If you need them in `switch` statements I suggest to split strings into characters. In your case this would give macros like:

```
#define HASH_CALC(...) HASH_CALC0(5381, __VA_ARGS__, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
#define HASH_CALC0(p, x, ...) (x == 0 ? (p) : HASH_CALC1((p)*33+x, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define HASH_CALC1(p, x, ...) (x == 0 ? (p) : HASH_CALC2((p)*33+x, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define HASH_CALC2(p, x, ...) (x == 0 ? (p) : HASH_CALC3((p)*33+x, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define HASH_CALC3(p, x, ...) (x == 0 ? (p) : HASH_CALC4((p)*33+x, __VA_ARGS__)))

...
#define HASH_CALC64(p, x, ...) (x == 0 ? (p) : -1 /* shall never be used */)
```

Macro `HASH_CALC` expects variable number of characters as arguments. For example, the following is valid code:

```
switch (x) {
case HASH_CALC('f', 'o', 'o'):
   ...
case HASH_CALC('f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r'):
   ...
}
```

Comment: I like your answer as like you said your macros can be used in a switch-statement as well. Got just one question tough: Why the (x+0) in the macro instead of just x?

Comment: @xatian: It is a trick. There are 64 macros consuming at most 64 arguments. However if there is less arguments, remaining macros get empty string as parameter. So `x` may be empty and would give a syntax error because the expression would be `( == 0 ? ...)` With +0, this gives `( (+0) == 0 ? ...)`. It is not 100% clean :). This makes me thinking that you maybe do not need to enter the trailing 0 in HASH_CALC parameters.

Comment: Well ... I tested a bit and it seems your macro mirrors the string passed to it --> the resulting hash is wrong. After some thinking it makes sense :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could used the ternary operator:

```
#define HASH_CALCX(s)                \
   (strlen(s) == 5 ? HASH_CALC5(s) : \
    strlen(s) == 4 ? HASH_CALC4(s) : \
    strlen(s) == 3 ? HASH_CALC3(s) : \
    strlen(s) == 2 ? HASH_CALC2(s) : \
    strlen(s) == 1 ? HASH_CALC1(s) : some_error)
```

For this to be viable would depend the compiler's optimization reducing this expression to a single numerical constant.

**Update**: Worked-out example using gcc. Fine if the optimization level is set to 1, but not for 0.

Let foox.c be:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define HASH_CALC(h, s) ((h) * 33 + *(s))
#define HASH_CALC1(s) (HASH_CALC(5381, s)) // hash_calc_start = 5381
#define HASH_CALC2(s) (HASH_CALC(HASH_CALC1(s), s + 1))
#define HASH_CALC3(s) (HASH_CALC(HASH_CALC2(s), s + 2))
#define HASH_CALC4(s) (HASH_CALC(HASH_CALC3(s), s + 3))
#define HASH_CALC5(s) (HASH_CALC(HASH_CALC4(s), s + 4))

#define HASH_CALCX(s)                \
   (strlen(s) == 5 ? HASH_CALC5(s) : \
    strlen(s) == 4 ? HASH_CALC4(s) : \
    strlen(s) == 3 ? HASH_CALC3(s) : \
    strlen(s) == 2 ? HASH_CALC2(s) : \
    strlen(s) == 1 ? HASH_CALC1(s) : 0)

int main(void) {
   printf("%d\n", HASH_CALCX("foo"));
   return 0;
}
```

Then `gcc -S -O1 foox.c` gives:

```
        .file       "foox.c"
        .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
        .string     "%d\n"
        .text
.globl main
        .type       main, @function
main:
        leal        4(%esp), %ecx
        andl        $-16, %esp
        pushl       -4(%ecx)
        pushl       %ebp
        movl        %esp, %ebp
        pushl       %ecx
        subl        $20, %esp
        movl        $193491849, 4(%esp)
        movl        $.LC0, (%esp)
        call        printf
        movl        $0, %eax
        addl        $20, %esp
        popl        %ecx
        popl        %ebp
        leal        -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
        .size       main, .-main
        .ident      "GCC: (GNU) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**Update 2**: As a *minor* enhancement, I would definitely try to add a compile-time 'assert' to verify that only *literal* strings of a certain length are passed to the macro, because I am error-prone. For example, modify the above to read:

```
#define ASSERT_zero(e) (!sizeof(struct{int:!!(e);}))
#define HASH_CALCX(s)  (ASSERT_zero(strlen(s) <= 5) + \
   (strlen(s) == 5 ? HASH_CALC5(s) : \
   etc
```

The `ASSERT_zero()` macro is similar to BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(), and uses the 'sizeof bitfield' trick. It yields either:

- a compile error, when `e` is false, or
- the value zero.

This `ASSERT_zero()`  doesn't work for C++. And this extra check won't work for VS IIRC, because VS doesn't regard `strlen("foo")` as a compile-time constant.

Comment: I can confirm that this works --> Produces a compile-time constant. So its a valid workaround that I could use if no better answer (solution) is given ... thank you so far! (I actually don't even like the HASH_CALC1/HASH_CALC2/HASH_CALC3 stuff. This way I would get one more monster macro)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is amazing what it is possible to do with macros, is that the best /  most maintainable way to do this?

I'd be inclined to put the strings in another file, and use a perl script to generate the hashes and output a c++ source file containing the strings and the hashes in some convenient data structure.

Your makefile could be set up to rerun the perl script whenever the strings are changed.